# Unknown values in Hibernate discriminator column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, discriminator

How does Hibernate behave when it faces database records which has unknown values in discriminator column (e.g. in case they have been modified somehow) ?

E.g. I have:

```
   @DiscriminatorValue(value = "User") 
   public class User {}
```

But some records representing objects of this class have modified discriminator column to value "other". How will hibernate behave in such case?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate will throw a PersistemceException wrapping a WrongClassException when you try to load it.

As the discriminator value is not known, Hibernate will not know what to do with the data.

Comment: In case my type hierarchy has been changed I want to mark already persisted data to be "transparent" for hibernate. Is there any way to achieve this?